# 3DConnexion SpaceNavigator installation problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am on ROS electric with Ubuntu 11.10 and tried to setup my SpaceNavigator with [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/spacenav_node/Tutorials/UsingTheSpacenavNode).

But when I type in the command "sudo ./spacenavd -d" it does not recognize my device:

Console output:

```
Spacenav daemon svn-r87
failed to open config file /etc/spnavrc: No such file or directory. using defaults.
using device: /dev/input/event9
Wrong device, no relative events reported!
```

I tried different USB ports, and when the device is not connected it says "no spaceball found". So it is seeing the device, but does not recognize it correctly.

Has anyone an idea what I could do?

Thanks,
Regards Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45530/3dconnexion-spacenavigator-installation-problem/) by [Makus Noack](https://answers.ros.org/users/3003/makus-noack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-10-10**:
What product are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah i solved the problem by installing "spacenavd" in Ubuntu Software Center. This is a newer revision of the driver. I use the "SpaceNavigator" product from 3DConnexion

---

Originally posted by [Makus Noack](https://answers.ros.org/users/3003/makus-noack/) with karma: 36 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2